# PostgreSQL ERROR: syntax error at or near "varchar"

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm trying to alter the course_id column in the table 'course' but I keep getting this error:

```
CREATE TABLE course 
(
 course_id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
 title varchar(30), 
 dep_name varchar(10), 
 credits numeric(2,2) CHECK (credits>0)
);

ALTER TABLE takes ALTER COLUMN course_id varchar(10) REFERENCES course(course_id);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "varchar" LINE 1: ALTER TABLE takes
>   ALTER COLUMN course_id varchar(10) REFEREN...

Comment: where is takes table structure, and how you write a query in three different RDBMS, tag any one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altering a column's type and adding a foreign key on it are two different statements:

```
ALTER TABLE takes ALTER COLUMN course_id TYPE VARCHAR(10);

ALTER TABLE takes 
ADD CONSTRAINT takes_course_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_id) 
REFERENCES course(course_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is worng. It must be:

```
ALTER TABLE takes ALTER COLUMN course_id TYPE varchar(10) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

References should be made as below:
**In your case:**

```
Alter table takes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_takes_course_id FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(course_id)
```

Comment: @Piyush : Example i gave for easier understanding,,, doesn't mean you need to use the tablenames which has been posted by the user.

Comment: @knkarthick24 Thanks!
Should it be courseidfk or course_idfk?

Comment: Follow some standard like FK_tablename_columnname. 
In your case: **FK_takes_course_id**